# Please explain the purpose of following circuit

Tags: switches, analog, vco

This is the excerpt from the 2VCO synthesizer unit.
Someone, please, can explain me what is this strange arrangement with VCO2 Out jack through the switch inside of it? I understand that when the Jack is inserted I have clear VCO2 voice output. But when the jack is out, the switch inside of it shorts to 6/10. What is the purpose of it?
Big big thanks is advance.

[image]

Comment: Please don't thank in advance. Thank afterwards by accepting and upvoting useful answers.

Comment: @transistor I like it when people thank me in advance, saves me from writing an answer

Comment: who else will mention my advanced thanks?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing , it's an "Audity" of a drawing.

The author didn't know standard practice , so just invented a way to boost VCO2 with some kind switch on the tip which is usually done on the ring such as below.[image] This seems to show to show how to bridge/bypass a path when connected. R227 is a "really" tiny 27K resistor with I recall the old RCA 3080 OTA used as a V-Ctrl gain .

Maybe it belongs on one of these panels?
[image]

Comment: No . This is the schematics of the Kobol Expander I synth.